# How to Self Study Some particular Computer Science Subjects?

Tags: algorithms

this is my first time posting on stack exchange, so excuse my naivety. I'll be straight to the point. I did my Bsc in studying Games Technology. The degree wasn't so much computer science focused and I think I've missed on some core subjects that i really need to get done with. As far as I have identified I lack some key specific subjects that i need to work on. And I'll list them:

1. Computer Architecture
2. Operating Systems
3. Compilers and Programming Languages
4. Theory of computation

The road map i've planned to follow is:

1. Computer Systems: A programmers Perspectivev 3rd edition
2. Then read Modern Operating Systems, Tanenbaum
3. Then go for Computer Architecture, Fifth Edition: A Quantitative Approach
4. Then do Compilers | Stanford

Along the way I've scouted some courses from coursera and other MOOC's to help along the way. So what do You guys think? Any comments to help me will be highly appreciated. Please feel free to suggest me to add or subtract anything from the list. Thanks

P.S My programming skills(c++/c) , Math, data structures & algorithm skills are solid so that's already covered. Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad, opinion based and not really computer science.  I don't think it's appropriate here. That being said, I'd recommend looking up the syllabus from some university and just following that. They recommend textbooks, sometimes have lectures notes etc. When you have specific questions you can always come back here.

Comment: You can also hit [chat] once you can a few rep points across the whole SE network.

Comment: adrianN. Thanks for the advice, I'd surely do that and see how it goes. Raphael. I look forward to the Computer Science Chat. Thanks!.